# screen flickers after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gpu

I did a distro upgrade to 20.04. Right after rebooting, the screen started flickering and it won't stop. The flickering starts right after booting, before the desktop comes up. Everything else works, but this is making it damn near impossible to work. Any suggestions?

Computer: Dell Precision 7530 laptop, came with Linux pre-installed.

```
$ uname -a
Linux lux 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for mike: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Baffin [Radeon Pro WX 4130/4150]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:410-40f iomemory:400-3ff irq:131 memory:4100000000-41ffffffff memory:4080000000-40801fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:9e400000-9e43ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: I'm using the MATE (1.24.0) desktop.

Comment: I was able to boot with the previous kernel version (4.15.0-1087-oem) and the display is back to normal. But it would be nice if I could use the latest kernel like a civilized person.